# JS d3 bar plot does not show the data

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to create a bar chart using the d3 JS library.
I was trying to implement the code that is presented [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8952219) with slight changes but without success.

Here is my full code example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bar Chart</title>

        <!-- Reference style.css -->
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

        <!-- Reference minified version of D3 -->
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <div id="barplot" style='width: 600px; height: 500px; padding-left: 5px;'></div>
        <script>
var width = 400, height = 350;
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, left: 40, bottom: 20};

var svg2 = d3.select("#barplot").append("svg")
            .append("g")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);

createBarPlot();
updateBarPlot();

function createBarPlot(){
    svg2.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", "-.55em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

    svg2.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Cn0");
}

function updateBarPlot(){
    // Create data array of values to visualize
  var Cn0 = [{"sat": 2, "val": 15}, {"sat": 4, "val": 20}, {"sat": 10, "val": 11}];

    x.domain(Cn0.map(function(d) { return d.sat;}));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(Cn0, function(d) { return d.val;})]);

    svg2.selectAll("bar")
        .data(Cn0)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .style("fill", "steelblue")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.sat);})
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.val);})
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value);});
}

</script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

When I run it I am able to create the axis for the bar plot but I do not see any data on the chart.
I suspect the issue is in the `updateBarPlot()` method but I cant figure out whats wrong with it.
Any idea of how to fix that issue? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: For the height of the bars, it should be `y(d.val)`, not `y(d.value)`.

Comment: I think its just a type error in here.  Would it fix the overal problem?

Comment: Didn't you try it?

Comment: Just did. It fixed the part where I don't see any data thank you for that. However, I don't see the labeling of the x-Axis and under each bar and the domain of the y-Axis is between 0-1 instead of being between 0 and the max value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the labelling of the x-axis and domain of the y-axis are concerned, the calling of the axes should be done AFTER setting the respective domains i.e. `.call(xAxis)` and `.call(yAxis)` should be called once the domains are set (in the **updateBarPlot** function) as follows:

```
x.domain(Cn0.map(function(d) { return d.sat;}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(Cn0, function(d) { return d.val;})]);

svg2.select('.x.axis')
  .call(xAxis);

svg2.select('.y.axis')
  .call(yAxis);
```

Additionally, I've added some styling to the axes' paths and ticks:

```
<style>

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
```

Here's a snippet combining the above (and the typo fix mentioned by @Gerardo in the comments):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bar Chart</title>

        <!-- Reference style.css -->

        <!-- Reference minified version of D3 -->
 <style>

 .axis {
   font: 10px sans-serif;
 }

 .axis path,
 .axis line {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #000;
   shape-rendering: crispEdges;
 }

 </style>        
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <div id="barplot" style='width: 600px; height: 500px; padding-left: 5px;'></div>
        <script>
var width = 400, height = 350;
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, left: 40, bottom: 20};

var svg2 = d3.select("#barplot").append("svg")
         .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);

createBarPlot();
updateBarPlot();

function createBarPlot(){
    svg2.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

    svg2.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Cn0");
}

function updateBarPlot(){
    // Create data array of values to visualize
  var Cn0 = [{"sat": 2, "val": 15}, {"sat": 4, "val": 20}, {"sat": 10, "val": 11}];

    x.domain(Cn0.map(function(d) { return d.sat;}));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(Cn0, function(d) { return d.val;})]);

  svg2.select('.x.axis')
       .call(xAxis);

  svg2.select('.y.axis')
       .call(yAxis);

    svg2.selectAll("bar")
        .data(Cn0)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .style("fill", "steelblue")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.sat);})
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.val);})
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.val);});
}

</script>
      </body>
    </html>
```